# Failed to connect to a mongodb docker container from mongoose on host

Tags: mongodb, docker, mongoose, docker-compose

I'm trying to connect to mongodb running in docker from the app running on host using mongoose but it failed.

I can't use the port `27017` for the new mongodb container because it is used by other container. So I followed the guide here for setting it up using the [compose](https://hub.docker.com/_/mongo#-via-docker-stack-deploy-or-docker-compose).

Below are the snippets:

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3'

services:

  db:
    image: mongo:latest
    restart: always
    ports:
      - '8081:8081'
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: root1
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: password1
```

But when I do `docker-ps`,  port `27017` still there but I'm not sure if that causes an issue.

```
PORTS
0.0.0.0:8081->8081/tcp, 27017/tcp
```

Then I created a new user in `admin` database.

```
use admin
db.createUser(
  {
    user: "admin1",
    pwd: "password2",
    roles: [ { role: "userAdminAnyDatabase", db: "admin" }, "readWriteAnyDatabase" ]
  }
)
```

**server.js**

```js
const connectOption = {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  user: 'admin1',
  pass: 'password2',
  authSource: 'admin',
}
const mongoURL = 'mongodb://localhost:8081/app1';

mongoose.connect(mongoURL, connectOption)
  .then(() => console.log('MongoDB Connected'))
  .catch(error => console.log(error));
```

And the error I received is

```
{ 
  MongoNetworkError: failed to connect to server [localhost:8081] on first connect [MongoNetworkError: write EPIPE]
...
...
...
  name: 'MongoNetworkError',
  errorLabels: [ 'TransientTransactionError' ],
  [Symbol(mongoErrorContextSymbol)]: {} 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're running nodejs application as a docker-compose service, in `db` service remove `ports` section (including `- '8081:8081'`
 line). In `server.js`, change `const mongoURL = 'mongodb://localhost:8081/app1';` to `const mongoURL = 'mongodb://db:27017/app1';`.

If you want to access the db from host machine, change ports `8081:8081` to `<give-a-port-number>:27017`.

Comment: no I'm not running the node app as a docker-compose service. But yeah I read that on some SO questions.

Comment: then change `8081:8081` to `8081:27017`. it should work

Comment: mongodb by default listens on port 27017 which we mapped to 8081 on host machine. syntax is `host-port:container-port`